# Why is $z \mapsto E(e^zB_t)$ where $B_t$, $z\in \mathbb{C}$ is a Brownian motion is analytic.

Tags: complex-analysis, probability-theory, brownian-motion, analyticity, analytic-functions

$z \mapsto E(e^zB_t)$ where $B_t$, $z\in \mathbb{C}$ is a Brownian motion is analytic. I am looking at the proof that for a one dimensional Brownian motion $B_t$, $E e^{zB_t}=e^{tz^2/2}$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$. The proof uses the fact that $E^{izB_t}=e^{-tz^2/2}$ and $e^{ay}e^{-y^2/2}$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}$, and analytic functions agreeing on a real line must agree on the whole complex plane. However, I do not understand why $z \mapsto E(e^zB_t)$ is analytic in the first place. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Well, the mapping is holomorphic, isn't it? There is no trouble differentiating with respect to $z$...

Comment: @saz what justifies the interchange of the integral and differentiation here? Lebesgue's differentiation theorem doesn't seem to apply here as we're differentiating over $z$ and not real number $t$.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/842942/36150 (... you have to replace the integral wrt Lebesgue measure $\int_0^1 \dots \, dt$ by an integral wrt a probability measure $\int_{\Omega} \dots \, d\mathbb{P}$).

Comment: @saz Thank you that clears me up. Can you help me with this question as well? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2309217/proof-of-the-markov-property-of-bm-using-intersection-stable-generators